# Connection established. Data is not collected from DB2 using SSMA

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, db2, database-migration

I'm able to connect to DB2 via SSMA.Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn890647(v=sql.110).aspx

However, just after the connection got established, I'm getting the error "Error occurred while collecting data" in SSMA. I referred this

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00440n.html

Still, getting the same error. I'm new to DB2 and need to migrate data from DB2 to SQL Server Could anyone please help what could be wrong and what steps to be followed (how) to fix this?

Comment: Might be an unsupported DB2 version. Which version/platform are you connecting to? You might also try the IBM OLEDB provider instead of the one from Microsoft.

Comment: Its DB2 400 and I series machine.

Comment: Well, there you go: The SSMA document you linked to says it supports DB2 for z/OS and LUW only.

Comment: Which link? I didn't find that in my link.Please give link?

Comment: The very first link in your own question; did you read it?

Comment: Got it : SSMA is designed to work with DB2 on z/OS version 9.0 and 10.0 or DB2 on LUW version 9.8 and 10.1 or later versions and SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2014. Is there any other ways?